# How Do I Shoot a Projectile into the Direction the Player is Facing?

Tags: c#, game-physics, unity-game-engine, projectile

I am creating a 2D side-scroller video game in Unity using c#. I have created the script that makes the player face the direction that the arrow key that was pressed was pointing to (when the right arrow is pressed, the player faces right. When the left arrow is pressed, the player faces left).

However, I cannot figure out how to make the harpoon that the player shoots point in the direction the player is facing. I have found many questions on Stack Overflow asking questions like this, but none of their answers worked for me.

Can anyone please tell me how to make the harpoon the player shoots face the direction the player is facing? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code that I use-
**PLAYER SCRIPT**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playerMove : MonoBehaviour {

// All Variables
public float speed = 10;
private Rigidbody2D rigidBody2D;
private GameObject harpoon_00001;
private bool facingRight = true;

void Awake () {

    rigidBody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    harpoon_00001 = GameObject.Find("harpoon_00001");

}

void Update () {

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && !facingRight) {
    Flip();
}

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && facingRight) {
    Flip();
}

}

void Flip () {

facingRight = !facingRight;

Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
theScale.x *= -1;
transform.localScale = theScale;

}

void FixedUpdate () {
    float xMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float yMove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    float xSpeed = xMove * speed;
    float ySpeed = yMove * speed;

    Vector2 newVelocity = new Vector2(xSpeed, ySpeed);

    rigidBody2D.velocity = newVelocity;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    Instantiate(harpoon_00001,transform.position,transform.rotation);

}

} 
}
```

**HARPOON SCRIPT**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class harpoonScript : MonoBehaviour {

// Public variable 
public int speed = 6;
private Rigidbody2D r2d;

// Function called once when the bullet is created
void Start () {
// Get the rigidbody component
r2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

// Make the bullet move upward
float ySpeed = 0;
float xSpeed = -8;

Vector2 newVelocity = new Vector2(xSpeed, ySpeed);
r2d.velocity = newVelocity;

}

void Update () {

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
    float xSpeed = -8;
}

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
    float xSpeed = 8;
}

}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) //hero hits side of enemy
{

        Destroy(other.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>());     //Remove collider to avoid audio replaying
        other.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;     //Make object invisible
        Destroy(other.gameObject, 0.626f); //Destroy object when     audio is done playing, destroying it before will cause the audio to stop

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already defining a variable **facingRight** to know the direction of the the player. You can use that knowledge to control the harpoon.
For example:

```
// this line creates a new object, which has harpoonScript attached to it.
// In unity editor, you drag and drop this prefab(harpoon_00001) into right place.
// transform.position is used for the starting point of the fire. You can also add +-some_vector3 for better placement 
// Quaternion.identity means no rotation.
harpoonScript harpoon = Instantiate(harpoon_00001,transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as harpoonScript;
// Assuming harpoon prefab already facing to right
if (!facingRight) {
  // Maybe, not required
  harpoon.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 180f); // Face backward
  Vector3 theScale = harpoon.transform.localScale;
  theScale.y *= -1;
  harpoon.transform.localScale = theScale; // Flip on y axis
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what `Harpoon harpoon = Instantiate(harpoon_00001,transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as Harpoon;` does? I'm new to c#, and I'm not sure I understand what it means

Comment: I tried to use your code, but Unity says that `Assets/Scripts/playerMove.cs(54,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Harpoon' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?` Is Harpoon the name of a script? Is Harpoon a GameObject?

Comment: Sorry for the misspell. Hapoon is actually your harpoonScript class. But, I just typed that way.

Comment: I don't have any more errors, but the harpoon still doesn't go the right way, and the inspector says `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
playerMove.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/playerMove.cs:60)` every time I press enter. I think that I'm still missing something...

Comment: You need to assign it at the editor. You know, drag and drop the prefab of the harpoonScript at the correct place in the inspector window of playerScript. If you have a problem with what's a prefab or inspector window, I would suggest to watch a decent tutorial about unity. Also, if you search NullReferenceException and unity in here, you can find out what's the problem.